# Req.params.id is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to access the `id` of a user when rendering its profile page by accessing the route `/users/:id` in `app.js`. This route his handled by the middleware `app.use('/users/:id', userProfile);`.

The error I'm getting is `404 Error: Not Found`. According to what is returned to the client, it's handled by the middleware in `app.js` following the routes declaration with the comment 'catch 404 and forward to error handler'. I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Where's the error in my code?

### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// include routes
var mainPage = require('./routes/mainPage');
var users = require('./routes/user');
var userProfile = require('./routes/userProfile');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// routes
app.use('/', mainPage);
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/users/:id', userProfile);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

### userProfile.js

```
var User = require('../models').sequelize.models.User;
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findById({
        id: req.params.id
    })
    .then(function(user) {
        if(!user) {
            var err = new Error('Not Found');
            err.status = 404;
            next(err);
        } else
            res.render('userProfile', { user: user }); 
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

### userProfile.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    #page-wrapper
        .container
            h2 User #{user.id}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your app.js, change

```
app.use('/users/:id', userProfile);
```

to

```
app.use('/users', userProfile);
```

since you've already specified `/:id`, inside your userProfile.js